# WPF C# DataGrid - use RowDetailsTemplate to show another DataGrid

Tags: wpf, datagrid, rowdetailstemplate

i have a WPF dataGrid with unknown Rows/Columns. This "outer" dataGrid in my xaml:

```
<DataGrid Name="dataGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=CurrentTable.DefaultView, IsAsync=False}
                          AutoGenerateColumns="True" 
                          AutoGeneratingColumn="DataGrid_AutoGeneratingColumn"
                          SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}">
```

inside of this DataGrid i want to have a RowDetailsTemplate. When selecting / clicking onto a row, i want another DataGrid to be shown. For test issues (i thought, it was a good idea), i just used:

```
<DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
        <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Path=CurrentTable.DefaultView, IsAsync=False}"/>
      </DataTemplate>
    </DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
```

This does not work with following error message:

System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'CurrentTable' property not found on 'object' ''DataRowView' (HashCode=26691149)'. BindingExpression:Path=CurrentTable.DefaultView; DataItem='DataRowView' (HashCode=26691149); target element is 'DataGrid' (Name=''); target property is 'ItemsSource' (type 'IEnumerable')

Comment: You need to define the correct RowDetailsTemplate.
Have you seen the https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18970386/wpf-datagrid-inside-datagrid-rowdetailstemplate ?

Comment: @Anton yes i did, but this does not help. the columns in your example are given, while i dynamically add columns to the inner grid. that is the difference and the reason why yours dont work ;/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `DataContext` of the inner `DataGrid` in the `RowDetailsTemplate` is the `DataRowView` of the current row in the outer `DataGrid`.

For your binding to work, you could use a `{RelativeSource}` that binds to the `DataContext` of the parent (outer) `DataGrid`:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Path=DataContext.CurrentTable.DefaultView, 
    RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGrid}}"/>
```

Comment: this helped me a lot! thank you. i mark this as answer.